# Subclassed React Component throw errors when parent class access state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

You have an application that uses react and redux. Let's say you have two React components, Component A and Component B. Component B is a subclass of Component A. Everything works fine at this point. But, now it's necessary to access the state in Component A using `mapStateToProps` and react-redux's `connect` method. You refresh the page and the app crashes with the following error `Cannot read property 'store' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined at ComponentB.Connect`. You check the logs and the error is being thrown from Component B's constructor, namely the `super(props)` method.

You've tried the following:

1. Using `contextTypes` in both files.
2. Having Component B access the state with the same code as Component A.

What could be the problem in this scenario that is throwing a `cannot access property store of undefined` error?

Here is some of the code involved:

*Signup/index.js*

```
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as selectors from '@@store/selectors';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const activeSite = selectors.getActiveSite(state);
    const domain = activeSite.properties.domain;
    return {
        domain
    };
 };

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignUp);
```

*Signup/Signup.js*

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      buttonDisabled: false,
      signUpState: 'new',
      newsletterStatus: 'Enter Your Email Address'
    };
    const {accounts} = config.get('campaignMonitor');
    this.list = accounts[this.props.domain].source;
    this.channelName = '';
  }

  set(property, value) {
    this[property] = value;
  }

  invalid() {
    this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: false,
      email: '',
      newsletterStatus: 'Please enter a valid email.'
    });
  }
  ....rest of methods, props validation, etc.
```

*Newsletter/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import SignUp from '@@modules/SignUp';
import * as selectors from '@@store/selectors';
import config from '@@config';
import './styles';

class Newsletter extends SignUp {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); <----- HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING THROWN
    const {accounts} = config.get('campaignMonitor');
    super.set('list', accounts[someRandomString].source);
  }

  render() {
    ....rest of methods, props validation, etc.
```

Comment: It's going to be extremely difficult for anyone to answer this question without any code being posted.  A minimal example that demonstrates this problem would go a long way.

Comment: @MichaelParker Thanks for the advice. Updated the post with the code involved